# How to group expressions to be matched as one?

Tags: regex

What i am trying to match is like this :

```
char-char-int-int-int
char-char-char-int-int-int
char-char-int-int-int-optionnalValue (optionalValue being a "-" plus letters after it
```

My current regep looks like this :

```
([A-Za-z]{1,2})([1-9]{3})("-"[\w])
```

In the end, the regexp should match any of these:

- AB001
- aB999
- Hm000
- en789
- rv005-ab

These should be invalid:

- ab (because only letters)
- abcfr (because too much letters)
- 158 (because only numbers)
- 78532 (because too much numbers)
- 123ab (because all letters should come before numbers, optionalValue exepted)
- a1b23 (because letters and numbers are mixed)

What am i doing wrong ? (please be gentle this is my first post ever on stackoverflow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `[A-Za-z]{1,2}` then the second example would not match as there a 3 *char-char-char*

Using `\w` would also match numbers and an underscore. If you mean letters like a-zA-Z you can use that in an optional group preceded by a hyphen `(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)?`

You could use

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{3}(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]{2,3}` Match 2 or 3 times a char A-Za-z
- `[0-9]{3}` Match 3 digits
- `(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)?` Optionally match a `-` and 1 or more chars A-Za-z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zuxx7X/1)

Or using word boundaries `\b` instead of anchors

```
\b[a-zA-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{3}(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)?\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kKVpZJ/1)

Comment: This worked as intended, the explanation helps a lot too. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected your regex below. Please give it a try.

```
([A-Za-z]{1,2})([0-9]{3})(-\w*)?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QrwBJs/2)